# Transparent action bar in actionbarshearlock activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

i am using  actionbarshearlock library in my project.
I want the action bar to be transparent.
How to do it? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: @Imram Khan: check my edited ans: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15873047/1168654

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

---

**without use actionbarshearlock:**

---

just add this line: `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);`

before `setContentView(R.Layout.Test)` in `onCreate`

and this line give you `TRANSPARENT ActionBar`

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ab_bg_black));
```

like:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ab_bg_black));
}
```

for R.drawable.ab_bg_black just add drawable colour in string.xml like:

```
<drawable name="ab_bg_black">#80000000</drawable>
```

---

**same way using actionbarshearlock:**

---

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(SampleList.THEME); //Used for theme switching in samples
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.overlay);

        //Load partially transparent black background
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ab_bg_black));

}
```

---

**Edited:** **`Start listview After Actionbar.`**

[image]

if you are using actionbarshearlock then just do like below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="?actionBarSize" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Dhaval Sodha Parmar thanks very much you save my day
one question more I have a list and my list should be below the actionbar

Comment: one question more I have a list, and my list should be below the actionbar how to do that

Comment: Dhaval Sodha Parmar greate.
I have a tabs also below the action bar.
and i want the tabs to be transparent.
also padding from top should include tabs

Answer (score 2):

try this code, but I'm not sure that is exactly what you need:

```
 bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```